# Shading polygons with d3

Tags: d3.js

Before heading down the wrong road, can anyone explain if this is entirely possible:

I have the following code:

```
var path = d3.geo.path();
var svg = d3.select("#d3Map").append("svg");
var countries = svg.append("g").attr("id", "countries");
d3.json("scripts/plugins/d3-master/examples/data/world-countries.json", function (json) {
  d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.equirectangular().scale(1500)));
});
```

Whcich sure enough loads and displays the countries of the world.  Works perfect.

However what I want to be able to do is change the colour on a handful of those countries.

Having looked at the SVG generated, there doesn't seem to be an ID for the country (even though the JSON file does have a 'name' attribute).

Is there any possible way of doing something similar to:

Highlight(countryName,RGB)

Or am I using the wrong tool here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.equirectangular().scale(1500)))
  .attr("fill", "#c00")// <- Set color like this, or pass a function
// Or
  .attr("id", function(feature) {
    /* something like: return feature.properties.id; */
  })
// Or
  .attr("class", function(feature) {
    return feature.population > 1e6 ? 'populous' : 'rural';
  });
```

Comment: Your last example has certainly helped immensely!!!  Having read the d3 documentation thoroughly I can now understand but your example certainly has helped so my thanks.